# How to change header text align to right in Date Picker UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-community-toolkit

```
<DatePicker x:Name="PatientDateOfBirthPicker"
                    SelectedDateChanged="PatientDateOfBirthPicker_SelectedDateChanged"
                    Header="بەرواری لە دایک بوون"
                    DayFormat="day"
                    MonthFormat="{}{month.integer}"
                    YearFormat="{}{year.full(4)}"
                    YearVisible="True"
                    FontFamily="NRT Reg"
                    FontSize="18" 
                    FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
                    Width="400">
        </DatePicker>
```

**How to change header text align to right tried both FlowDirection="RightToLeft" and FlowDirection="LeftToRight" it give me the same result**

[this is my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7par.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mark Feldman's answer is correct. You just need to change the header of the DataPicker and set the `FlowDirection` to **RightToLeft**

The code:

```
 <DatePicker x:Name="PatientDateOfBirthPicker"
                
                DayFormat="day"
                MonthFormat="{}{month.integer}"
                YearFormat="{}{year.full(4)}"
                YearVisible="True"
                FontFamily="NRT Reg"
                FontSize="18" 
                FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
                Width="400">
        <DatePicker.Header>
            <TextBlock Text="بەرواری لە دایک بوون" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" />
        </DatePicker.Header>
    </DatePicker>
```

The result:
[image]

Comment: thank you it is completely resolved my issue

Answer (score 0):

The Header property is of type `object`, so you can replace it with a TextBlock and set the TextAlignment:

```
<DatePicker x:Name="PatientDateOfBirthPicker"                    
                DayFormat="day"
                MonthFormat="{}{month.integer}"
                YearFormat="{}{year.full(4)}"
                YearVisible="True"
                FontFamily="NRT Reg"
                FontSize="18" 
                FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
                Width="400">
    <DatePicker.Header>
        <TextBlock Text="بەرواری لە دایک بوون" TextAlignment="Right"/>
    </DatePicker.Header>
</DatePicker>
```

ALternatively you can replace the HeaderTemplate:

```
<DatePicker x:Name="PatientDateOfBirthPicker"
                Header="بەرواری لە دایک بوون"                   
                DayFormat="day"
                MonthFormat="{}{month.integer}"
                YearFormat="{}{year.full(4)}"
                YearVisible="True"
                FontFamily="NRT Reg"
                FontSize="18" 
                FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
                Width="400">
    <DatePicker.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header, ElementName=PatientDateOfBirthPicker}" TextAlignment="Right"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DatePicker.HeaderTemplate>
</DatePicker>
enter code here
```